# Standard deviation coming repeatedly greater than the mean

Tags: mean, standard-deviation

I had carried out an experiment to assess the antioxidant potential of two microbes. There were several assays. Some of the reads showed low values with a standard deviation greater than the mean e.g. 0.004+/-0.006 mgGAE/ml, 0.11+/-0.2 mgGAE/ml. Does this mean my assay method is erroneous? I have considered carrying out assays for 4 replicates including 4 strain replicates. I used Graphpad prism 6.0 software for analysis.

Comment: What do you mean some reads had standard deviation values?  Standard deviation is a summary measure and doesn't vary by sample.  You may also want to clarify what you mean by terms like "assay" since non-biologists may not know what you're talking about.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Sorry about not being explicit. By assays I meant there were different designs and arrangement of samples for the experiment based on the biochemical reactions involved. And in these we look for the presence of specific compounds by taking the absorbance readings at 415nm in a spectrophotometer. For each sample, the assay was carried out for 5 times.

Comment: PS. The readings at 415 are the ones with error value greater than the mean as I stated before. Is it that my experiment is faulty? Cause if confidence limit is 95, how can this be possible..

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean.  What is an error value?  How is the mean calculated?  What are you constructing a confidence interval on?

Comment: Mean is calculated from the readings at 415nm.